# Wpa_supplicant configuration file for open hidden network

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, nmcli, wpa-cli

I am unable to connect to a open hidden network (without password) The network is the following (from `iwlist wlan0 scan`)

```
  Cell 0 - Address: 11:22:33:44:55:66
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.### GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=50/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:""
```

**What is the right `wpa_supplicant.config` to connect to this open hidden network?**

In particular **What is the `key_mgmt` field for this open network?** (instead of `WPA-PSK`)

Wrong guess:

```
network={
ssid="11:22:33:44:55:66
scan_ssid=1
mode=0
proto=WPA2
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
group=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
priority=1
psk=""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `key-mgmt=NONE` in your configuration file.

This stanza is reported to work (haven't tried myself personally though):

```
network={
    ssid="any"
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```